# Reading a UDP stream by ffmpeg libavcodec

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, libavcodec

I want to read a video stream using ffmpeg libavcodec from a UDP address like udp://:1500. I am using this code:

```
char *url = "udp://:1500";
char *format = "mpegts";

AVInputFormat *fmt = NULL;
AVFormatContext *oc = NULL;

int res;

fmt = av_find_input_format(format);
res = avformat_open_input(&oc, url, fmt , NULL);
if(res!=0){
     printf("Could not open the stream\n");
     exit(1);
}
```

But when I run this code, the program halts forever after executing res = avformat_open_input(&oc, url, fmt , NULL);

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My stream was created with this:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -vcodec copy -f h264 udp://machine:1500
```

Your code worked for me after I changed

```
char *format = "mpegts";
```

to

```
char *format = "h264";
```

My guess is that your stream isn't in the format you think it's in.

In fact, when I removed the `fmt` variable entirely and passed NULL instead, libav discovered the format for me.

See also: [Code that starts the same but has a lot more comments.](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial/blob/master/0_hello_world.c)